# Neo4j 3.4.4 - Slow processing if using LIST

Tags: performance, neo4j

Two identical queries in terms of processing. Run multiple times to avoid cache distortions on timing:

```
MATCH (p:Pathway {name: {PNAME}}), (t:target {symbol: {TNAME}}) MERGE (p)-[:INVOLVES]->(t)
```

Above runs 11,100 commands per second

```
UNWIND {LIST} AS i MATCH (p:Pathway  {name: i.PNAME}), (t:target {symbol: i.TNAME}) MERGE (p)-[:INVOLVES]->(t)
```

Above runs 547 commands per second on the same data set.

Windows 10 Pro, 64GB Ram, SSD, Python 3.7

There are unique constraints on both variables in the statements above and both indices are ON.

The LIST statement in other situations is dramatically faster so I like using it for bulk operations. I tested on Neo4j 3.4 and today on 3.4.4 and Python 3.6 and 3.7. Using latest neo4j-driver. Same results. My guess is query planning is not using the index. About 40,000 nodes in Pathway and 25,000 in target.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Query plan when using a list. For this profile, the list contained one record.

Suggestion: Can the plan optimizer calculate the number of records in the list to determine whether to scan in all records or to individually use the unique index. Maybe set a threshold of if less than 10% of rows will be needed use unique index. Just a thought for Neo4j developers. In the meantime I dropped using the LIST version.

[image]

Comment: Please PROFILE both queries and add their query plans (with all elements expanded) to your question, that should help out, and you'll be able to tell if indexes aren't being used.

Comment: For the query using the LIST, two NodeIndexScans are used with thousands of db hits. For the other query, two NodeUniqueIndexSeek(Locking) are used with 2 db hits each.

Comment: Can you add the query plans to your description?

Comment: Added plan for LIST query. Thanks

Comment: Can you expand all elements of the plan and then replace the image? It's hard to see what some of the operators are doing without the elements expanded

Answer (score 0):

The `UNWIND {list}` is what's killing you. You are completely changing the dynamic of the query from one to the other.

The first query is a simple 2 node lookup, The second query is creating a bunch of rows, and then doing a per row 2 node match.

In the first example, it is obvious to the Cypher Planner to use the index to match. In the later, The planner doesn't know for sure what the best way to proceed is. Run against the index for every row, or scan all the nodes to try and get what it needs in one pass through (or something else)?

You can use Cypher [hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/using/) to try and help the Planner choose the right one, but in your case, use the first query. The first query is simpler and easier for the Cypher planner to plan, and the planner will actually cache the plan so that it doesn't need to figure out what to do each time you re-run it. (The second query will too, but as far as I can tell, it is only trying (and failing) to reproduce the performance boost of using a parameter-ized query, so why not just use the Neo4j built in one?).